# PIP uninstall not looking into /usr/local

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I installed several packages (among them patsy and statsmodels) with pip 1.3.1 in kubuntu 13.04. They were put into /usr/local/lib, instead of /usr/lib. When using pip freeze or pip list, these packages appear fine, and are usable in python. However, when I use pip uninstall I get "Can't uninstall 'statsmodels'. No files were found to uninstall." The structure of install packages in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages seem correct, and installed-files.txt has everything listed. How do I make pip see these files and uninstall them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really have a solution for the pip path lookup, but deleting `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_PACKAGE_NAME` did the trick for me. At the very least it allowed me to install anew.